Kubernetes informer not listening to cluster events
I have local kubermetes cluster with below version:
Client Version: v1.31.2
Kustomize Version: v5.4.2
Server Version: v1.30.6+k3s1

I am writing application using kubernetes java-client:
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.kubernetes</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
    <version>19.0.0</version>
</dependency>

this is my code:
        ApiClient client = Config.defaultClient();
        Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(client);

        // Initialize the CoreV1Api to interact with Pods
        CoreV1Api coreApi = new CoreV1Api();

        // Define the namespace to watch (can be changed to any valid namespace)
        String namespace = "demo-namespace"; // Modify to your desired namespace

        // Create the SharedInformerFactory
        SharedInformerFactory factory = new SharedInformerFactory();

        // Watch Pods in the specified namespace
        SharedIndexInformer<V1Pod> podInformer = factory.sharedIndexInformerFor(
                params -> coreApi.listNamespacedPodCall(namespace, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, true, null),
                V1Pod.class,
                V1PodList.class
        );

        // Add event handlers for the Pods
        podInformer.addEventHandler(new ResourceEventHandler<V1Pod>() {
            @Override
            public void onAdd(V1Pod pod) {
                System.out.println("Pod added: " + pod.getMetadata().getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(V1Pod oldPod, V1Pod newPod) {
                System.out.println("Pod updated: " + oldPod.getMetadata().getName());
            }

            @Override
            public void onDelete(V1Pod pod, boolean deletedFinalStateUnknown) {
                System.out.println("Pod deleted: " + pod.getMetadata().getName());
            }
        });

        // Start all registered informers (this includes the Pod informer)
        factory.startAllRegisteredInformers();

whenever I run the program, neither I get any exception nor any event is listened and printed. Is anything missing here?
